# Issue with text in a Intel 82945G Express Chipset Family

Tags: 11.04, drivers, xorg, intel-graphics

I am on Ubuntu 11.04 and the text in all the applications often looks with visual artifacts. I have installed xserver-xorg-video-intel.

Attached a image so you can appreciate.

[image]

lshw -c video output:

```
      *-display               
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 2
           bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
           version: 02
           width: 32 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
           configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
           resources: irq:16 memory:dfe00000-dfe7ffff ioport:8800(size=8) memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:dfe80000-dfebffff
```

In the text selected in green you can see the 'Online', 'File' and 'hassle' words cut.

Comment: Where? the green stuff 'cause i don't see anything wrong

Comment: please specify the model of your VGA, add the output of "lshw -c video" to you first post

Comment: If of any help I have same graphic chip and running 11.04 without such issues

Comment: Is this question still active?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the screen resolution is too high, and your VGA is reaching it's limits. I had the same problem with a pci S3 card when I used it above 1024*768.
The problem is hardware related, you can try increasing the shared memory in BIOS or you can buy an AGP card.